# ES6 import, node libraries and my modules

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, npm-scripts

*I'm learning node but have never used ES6/javascript/TypeScript before, so please bear with me...*

I'm trying to write nodejs application in plain ES6. From the following example (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684265/2125837)),

```
import fs from 'fs';
export default class Animal {

  constructor(name){
    this.name = name ;
  }

  print(){
    console.log('Name is :'+ this.name);
  }
}

import Animal from 'path/to/Animal.js';
```

We can see there are ***two*** kinds of `import`s, the ES6 way of `require`. One is without path (`import fs from 'fs';`), and the other is with path.

So my first confusion is, from [here](http://2ality.com/2017/05/es-module-specifiers.html) it says,

> For compatibility with CommonJS and in preparation for future features, relative paths that don’t start with ./ or ../ are not allowed (in ES6):

```
// Not allowed:
import * as foo from 'foo.mjs';
import * as foo from 'lib/foo.mjs';
```

So is `import fs from 'fs'` right or wrong?

The plain ES6 nodejs application I'm trying to write is based on a `npm` module, but because it is almost updated daily, I'm pulling from its git instead doing

```
npm install mydepmod
```

This in turn makes its sample code of which starts with

```
import { mydepmod } from 'mydepmod'
```

not working for me. The error I'm getting is,

```
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mydepmod'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/example/the-test.js:19:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

so my last question is how to make it works?

BTW, I tried its docker installing and running from docker (which starts with `import { mydepmod } from 'mydepmod'`) work without any problem, so I assume if I do `npm install mydepmod`, it should work as well.

All in all, how can I make my git pulled dependent module works just like a `npm install`ed one. Thx.

Comment: Simple to say,without path way is `node module` and other is your project file ,here are more information about `import`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking how to use node module just as node module, even thought I didn't do `npm install`, but `git get`. See my OP for updated error message, thx. @Cr.

Comment: without path and if isn't nodejs core module, import will find `node_module` floder under the project folder, if does not have this module, it will find `node_module` floder under the first level directory until the root directory. If haven't ,throw not found error.

Comment: Ah, gotya @Cr., having read your answer several times, I think I know the answer to my question (which I will try it out next). thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import using relative path with prefix './' then it loads module from that file, you can give full path like '/path/to/module'.

When you import any module without any path, then node look for that module

- in `node_modules` folder, either in that directory, or in any parent directory where `package.json` exists
- if it fails to load module from that directory, then node try to load that module from global `node_modules` folder which is in users directory (e.g., `/usr/lib/node_modules/`).
- If node fails to load module at this stage, then it will throw error saying `Can not find module`.

[Here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/) is a detailed description about how require works. 
Require and Import/Export are similar, [this](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/javascript/nodejs-require-vs-es6-import-export.html) article gives difference between require and import/export.

For difference between local node_modules and global node_modules, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389974/locally-installed-versus-globally-installed-npm-modules) is a discussion.

Location of global node_modules is different in different os environment. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/2034794) answer:

On Unix systems they are normally placed in `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` when installed globally. If you set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

Windows XP - `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules`
Windows 7, 8 and 10 - `%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

Comment: Thx! I'll get back to you once I've made my git pulled dependent module works just like a npm installed one. BTW, is (my added) `/usr/lib/node_modules/` what you meant by _"is in users directory"_?

Comment: Laxmikant: have you noticed @Cr's answer, _"import will find node_module floder under the project folder, if does not have this module, it will find node_module floder under the first level directory until the root directory. "_, which is different than yours? Can you double check which saying is more correct please? My [new reading](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) seems to indicate his. Thx!